# Cannot access modules with ng-mock in angular unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, angular-mock

I am using Karma and Jasmine for my unit tests.  However, I am unable to mock or acquire the modules in my unit tests.  I keep getting the same error

```
 Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ha.module.core due to:
 Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'duScroll' is not available! You either
misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module  
ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

However, I am injecting the modules in the beforeEach function on top

```
    angular.mock.module('duScroll');
    angular.mock.module('ui.router');
    angular.mock.module('ha.module.utility');
    angular.mock.module('ha.module.core');
```

In my karma.config file I am requiring the js files

```
 files: [
    '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    '../node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    '../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'src/modules/utility/module.utility.built.js',
    'src/modules/utility/services/*.js',
    'src/modules/core/module.core.built.js',
    'src/modules/**/**/*.js',
    'src/modules/core/**/*.js',
    '../Templates/**/*.html',
    'tests2/**/*.js',
],
```

I have attached a screen shot to show what is showing up when I run karma.  I am getting the files to show up in my developer tools.

[image]

All I can wonder is if there is something else additional that I must do to get the modules initiated to run the tests?   The files are loaded after angular and angular mocks and they are loaded before my testing folder.  Not sure why I cannot get the modules though.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call `angular.mock.module`, it is enough to call `beforeAll(module('<module-name>'))` for each module you want to mock.

Then, to inject your controllers afterwards, you have to use

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
  // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
  $controller = _$controller_;
}));
```

Inforation from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-a-controller. Please visit it for more info.